# Why can’t I reset the state to the initial? [Redux]

Tags: reactjs, redux

I want to understand why this example does not work?

```
case "RESET":
  return initialState;
```

Setup some example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-bas-oqd4v?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

UPD: 
Problem in mutation

Comment: `rams[action.index].value = action.payload` is mutating. If you made pure components they would not even render the "changed" value

Comment: Can u explain? What you mean "is mutating"?

Comment: Can you explain a bit what 'does not work'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not mutate state in your reducer, you can set value like this

```
case 'CHANGE_PARAM':
  return {
    ...state,
    params: state.params.map((p, i) =>
      i === action.index
        ? { ...p, value: action.payload }
        : p
    ),
  };
```

Your input components are uncontrolled components and can't be set with any value because they lack a value property:

```
<input onChange={onChangeValue} />
```

Try this instead:

```
<input onChange={onChangeValue} value={props.value} />
```

Comment: I dont mutate, i get a copy: let params = [...state.params]. 
The question is different, why can't I reset state to initial?

Comment: @YourBuddy you make a shallow copy of an array and the set a property of of an object in that array. you are mutating. `var a =[{id:1}];var b = [...a];b[0].id=2;console.log(a[0].id)`